# Setup My Site Host on a hosted-name site - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

Is there any way to setup the My Site Host on a hosted-name site in Sharepoint 2013?  I am able to create a My Shit Host site using New-SPSite, but when I try to enable Self Service Site create on the web application I get "Cannot enable site creation because there is no site collection at "/" on the Web application."

To make it clear...I'm trying to only use hosted-name sites so after installing SP 2013 I ran the following:

New-SPWebApplication -Name 'X Sites' -hostHeader 'webapp.xxx.com' -port 80 -ApplicationPool XXXAppPool -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount 'corp\john') -AuthenticationProvider (New-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication)

Then made several site collections with:

New-SPSite 'http://NewSiteCollection.xxx.com' -HostHeaderWebApplication 'http://webapp.xxx.com' -Name 'A New Site' -Description 'My Site' -OwnerAlias 'corp\john' -language 1033 -Template 'STS#0'

Comment: Have you created a root site collection on that web app?

Comment: That might be my problem...I created several hosted-name sites, but I'm not sure how to create a root site?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue but after reading lots of blog's and read carefully this TechNet article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx), I finally find the way to create the Root ("/") site collection using HNSC and get MySites functional.

Kindling use the following PowerShell commands :

- First **create a root site collection**

> New-SPSite '**http: //servername**' -Name '**Root**' -Description '**Root site
>   collection (empty site template)**' -OwnerAlias '**account**' -language **1033**
>   -Template '**STS#1**' -ContentDatabase '**WSS_Content_Rootdb**'

Note that the root site collection must have the WebApplication URL's as name.

- Then **create a MySites site collection** using template 'SPSRSITEHOST#0' (and dedicated content database)

> New-SPSite '**http: //mysites.your-company.xy**' -hostheader '**http:
>   //servername**' -Name '**MySites**' -Description '**MySites Site Collection**'
>   -OwnerAlias '**account**' -Language **1033** -Template '**SPSRSITEHOST#0**' -ContentDatabase '**WSS-Content_MySites**'

- Finally set a **Managed Path**

> New-ManagedPath '**my**' -Hostheader

After all is done, go through the standard process to configure MySites functionnality on **User Profile Service**.

By doing all this, you'll be able to get MySites functionnality functional using Host-named site collection.

> http: //**mysites**.*your-company.xy*/**my**/*user-login*